# What is the C# DateTimeOffset equivalent in Go

Tags: c#, datetime, go

I have the following code which takes a string as input which is converted into UNIX time stamp. I want to do the same in golang but I am not able to recognize the struct or function which will give an equivalent of DateTimeOffset structure in Go.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var date = GetUtcTimestampFromAttribute();
        Console.WriteLine(date);
        if (date != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ToUnixTimeStamp(date.Value));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset? GetUtcTimestampFromAttribute()
    {
        var ticks = long.Parse("7036640000000");
        Console.WriteLine(ticks);
        return GetUtcTimestampFromTicks(ticks);
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset? GetUtcTimestampFromTicks(long ticks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new DateTimeOffset(ticks, TimeSpan.Zero));
        return ticks != 0 ?
            new DateTimeOffset(ticks, TimeSpan.Zero) :
            (DateTimeOffset?)null;
    }

    public static long ToUnixTimeStamp(DateTimeOffset timeStamp)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
        return Convert.ToInt64((timeStamp - epoch).TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

For example:

Input: 635804753769100000

Output: 1444878577

Corresponding Time in UTC : 10/15/2015 3:09:36 AM +00:00

Can someone please help me on a workaround to get the above result.

Thanks

Comment: Does the transformation works in both ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func TimeFromTicks(ticks int64) time.Time {
    base := time.Date(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix()
    return time.Unix(ticks/10000000+base, ticks%10000000).UTC()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(TimeFromTicks(635804753769100000))
}
```

Output:

```
2015-10-15 03:09:36.0091 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe the `time` package has everything you need and it is IMO the best time library I've worked with in any language. Example:

```
package main 

import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main(){

    // this is how you parse a unix timestamp    
    t := time.Unix(1444902545, 0)

    // get the UTC time
    fmt.Println("The time converted to UTC:", t.UTC())

    // convert it to any zone: FixedZone can take a utc offset and zone name
    fmt.Println(t.In(time.FixedZone("IST", 7200)))

}
```

**EDIT** Converting the time object back to a unix timestamp is simple:

```
t.Unix()
```

or

```
t.UnixNano()
```

Comment: I don't want a time zoned output. I need a Unix timestamp. I am getting using the c# but I am unable to put it in as go code.

Comment: @Prashant read the lib documentation, I just gave a simplified example. Basically a `time.Time` object can be converted to a unix timestamp in second or nanosecond resolution.

Comment: Yes @not_a_Golfer but my problem  is that I am not able to convert that input number into a valid  time object.

Comment: @Prashant why not? I've shown in my example how to do it. you just have to split your number into nanoseconds part and seconds part if it's in nano/micro resolution.

Comment: Can you please help me in splitting this long number into parts. I unable to understand how to split it.